# Different models of clients and other players in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on online FPS like Counter-Strike and overwatch.
In such games player can se only hands of their character, while other players can see full model.
How to realize it in unity?
Hope you got what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online multiplayer is an illusion.

You have to sync the game state between all players and visually show different things depending on if a player is the local player.

```
if(localPlayer) {
    // spawn hands with the gun
} else {
    // spawn the full player model
}
```